# How can I convert a string in JsonObject in Kotlin

Tags: android, json

I have a string that I want to convert in JsonObject, not in JSONObject. This is string can change the keys and values dinamically

String

```
{"toast":"test","from":"test","to":"test"}
```

How can I do it

Comment: Using JsonReader? Where is the problem?

Comment: how can achive this in kotlin? can you give me an example please?

Comment: You can use gson library for same. Gson().fromJson(string) can be used for converting string in to java object.

Answer (score 0):

create a data class

```
data class Example(
var toast:String?=null,
var from:String?=null,
var to:String?=null

)
```

Than use this where you got this gson data

```
var data = Gson().fromJson(jsonResponse,Example::class.java)
```

and than access these data using keyword data.toast